# Can the IP address of Apache Tomcat be changed from localhost to someother IP Address?

Tags: tomcat, networking

I am new to using Servlet as well as Apache Tomcat, however, I wanted to know if it is possible to create a Server on one Computer and connect Various Other Computers to it, ofcouse all Computers being on the same LAN. I have used Apache Tomcat but it has localhost i.e. 127.0.0.1 as it's Default IP, however I would like to change it to the IP Address of the Server Computer in the Network. Is this Possible? If Yes then how should I change the IP Address?

Comment: Please try to use small titles with right keywords while keeping it a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, various computers can connect to one server e.g. Tomcat.

Different servers use different policies to assign IP addresses to nodes that connect to LAN. Your network administrator may assign your computer a fix IP address or if a DHCP service is running on server, then server would assign you an IP address dynamically as you connect to LAN.

You can access Tomcat server using other IP address in addition to localhost. Actually localhost point to the computer its used on. For example, if you want to access you Tomcat server on some other computer on the network. You can type your computer IP address on other computer web browser, the same page shall become visible. For exampl if your Tomcat is running on port 8080 and server has assigned you 172.168.1.4 IP. you can go to other computer and access the tomcat typing in browser: http://172.168.1.14:8080/

Answer (score 0):

> It has localhost, i.e. 127.0.0.1, as its default IP

No it doesn't. The default address of Tomcat is not 127.0.0.1 but 0.0.0.0, unless you change it, via the `address` attribute of the `Connector` element in `server.xml`.

Normally 0.0.0.0 is what you want.

You can set it to any local IP address you like, but you can't set it to the IP address of another host.